# Debug app segmentation fault? Compiler's fault?

Tags: android, gcc, segmentation-fault

I am currently compiling Android Linaro build 11.11 (staging-panda) for pandaboard.

In the build process, Android compiles some tools with the host gcc compiler. On my Linux Mint 12 (Ubuntu-11.10 based), I have gcc-4.6 installed by default.

I built Android, everything runs fine, pandaboard booted, but then starting any application will lead to segmentation fault (signal 11 in logcat).

I then learned that Linaro built this release with gcc-4.5, not 4.6 version. I installed it using apt-get. I removed out/ directory and rebuild Android entirely.

The compilation runs fine, but the linker insults me:

```
g++-4.5 -Wl,-rpath-link=out/target/product/pandaboard/obj/lib -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN/../lib -Lout/host/linux-x86/obj/lib   -Wl,--no-undefined   -m32          out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/acp_intermediates/acp.o     -Wl,--whole-archive   -Wl,--no-whole-archive  out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libhost_intermediates/libhost.a   -o out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/acp_intermediates/acp 
g++-4.5 -Wl,-rpath-link=out/target/product/pandaboard/obj/lib -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN/../lib -Lout/host/linux-x86/obj/lib   -Wl,--no-undefined   -m32          out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/mkbootfs_intermediates/mkbootfs.o     -Wl,--whole-archive   -Wl,--no-whole-archive     -o out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/mkbootfs_intermediates/mkbootfs 
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.4/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.4/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.4/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.4/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The linker grabs the 64bit libraries of gcc-4.5, although it probably for 32bit version. So far, here are the things I tried, without success:

1. re-do the package installation following [these instructions](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html)
2. sudo ldconfig
3. reboot my machine
4. I looked into removing gcc-4.6 to get only gcc-4.5 on my machine.
   But synaptic showed so many dependencies needed to be uninstalled,
   that I didn't make that step :)

Finally I've been told to install gcc-4.5-multilib and g++-4.5-multilib. It worked, and the build got further. I start the panda, still the apps (eg com.android.launcher) fails to launch. I know this is an assumption, but I think that this segfault is somehow linked to the compiler.

My questions are simple:

1. Is com.android.launcher cross-compiled or compiled with host 32bit
   compiler? What keyword should I look for to find the associated command in the build log?
2. How can I debug this segmentation fault? In particular, I am looking
   for starting com.android.launcher with the "am" command.
3. Will strace provide valuable information for this issue?

Thanks heaps.

Comment: *tl;dr* but some quick help: `strace` may give you a rough indication at what point the thing crashes. `gdb` can give a much more precise indication but you need to: 1) have a working `gdb`, 2) build the crashing binary (or library?) with `-ggdb`, 3) know how to use `gdb`.

Comment: I used a few times strace, but can't remember if it can help on segfault. gdb is quite easy to start on android, and i used it thoroughly few months ago (on non-android linux on ARM), but bugs I was chasing were not segfaults :). So I am in front of the cross road right now... I knew -g but didn't know about -ggdb, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **gdb**. Requirements:

`#` is the target shell, although being root is not mandatory
`$` is the host shell

1. The app must be compiled in debug mode 
   `LOCAL_CFLAGS += -g`
2. start gdbserver on the target: 
   `# gdbserver :5039 </system/bin/executable>` 
   (or) 
   `# gdbserver :5039 --attach <pid>`
3. forward tcp port to adb connection: 
   `$ adb forward tcp:5039 tcp:5039`
4. start gdbclient on the host: 
   `$ gdbclient :5039 <executable>`

If you struggle with `gdbclient`, check `build/envsetup.sh` where the function is defined: 
`$ type gdbclient`
 Adding the verbose `-v` option might be of some help. Also if your executable is not in `system/bin`, you'll definitely need to modify `build/envsetup.sh` as it is hard-coded.

Some more information can be found [here](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/gdb).

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: @martinkunev fixed